# iOS/Android app using third party payment gateways

Tags: android, ios, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

Apple and Google have clear rules about about having to use in-app purchases and disallowing third party payment gateways.

I'm looking at building a web app and native app, that has two user types. The web app would be for user type A who can post listings, this would be free. The native app would be for user type B, who pay a subscription to access those listings made on the web app.

Reading the app store guidelines would the native app need to use IAP's for the subscription? As that content wouldn't be available on the web app. To be clear - to avoid having to use IAP's (and use a third party payment gateway instead) would the functionality of the native app also have to be on the web app (so both use types can use the web app)? And if this is the case can I link to create an account from the native app?

I am thinking of apps such as FreeAgent as an example, which allows all functionality on both the web and native app, and does not use IAP / IAS.

[See the app store guidelines here:](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase)

`3.1.3(b) Multiplatform Services: Apps that operate across multiple platforms may allow users to access content, subscriptions, or features they have acquired in your app on other platforms or your web site, including consumable items in multi-platform games, provided those items are also available as in-app purchases within the app.`

Comment: The answers are in your question. "Apple and Google have clear rules about about having to use in-app purchases" and "...provided those items are also available as in-app purchases within the app". You must use IAP. You can't link from the native app to your website for subscription payment. You will be rejected.  I think if you figure out how much it costs you to set up an external payment processor, pay their fees, have to provide customer support, handle refunds etc  then the ease of implementation, low customer friction and high customer trust makes paying apple 15% a good deal

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks but that doesn’t clarify the answer. Apps such as Spotify and FreeAgent are subscription based and do link to their websites with external payment gateways, and they do not use IAP. 

So I’m asking is that acceptable ONLY if your website also offers the same functionality as the native app? Which is what the store rules appear to be stating.

Comment: Spotify does not link to their website. If you select "premium" in te Spotify app it just shows you the premium plans and benefits and says "you can't upgrade to premium in the app" there is no pricing nor a direct link to the web site. You can log in to the app and make use of the premium subscription you paid for on their web site.

Comment: The second clause only applies to consumable in app purchases in games, so for your subscription you can use the same tactic as Netflix and Spotify; allow people to log in to your app and take advantage of the subscription they paid for via the web, but your app cannot link directly to your website or even provide a url.

Comment: I don't think it matters if your website doesn't offer the same functionality as your app, but your users will have a very fragmented and confusing experience if it doesn't. They have to find the website (somehow since you can't tell them what it is in the app) and pay, but then return to the app to make use of the subscription.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for the answers, most appreciated